# Select SQL Server table contents in xml format with xs:element namespace tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to create SQL code that would dynamically convert the results of a table to a XML format that resembles the one shown below but upon till now have not found a way to do so.

Table sample:

```
key name   age   
---------------
1   Anakin 23  
2   jill   40
```

XML

```
<xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="key" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Any suggestions or reading material that could help?

Comment: `FOR XML` clause?

Comment: Can you post the source sample data as a table?

Comment: I edited the post. It's a simple table with three columns.

Comment: Clarify: is your intent really to produce an XML schema from this table, or do you want XML results conforming to this schema? Also, since presumably there has to be *something* generating the XML conforming to this schema eventually, are you also going to do that in T-SQL or some other tool (in which case, that tool should also probably be responsible for the schema in the first place)?

Comment: I meant the XML results that correspond to this schema.

Comment: Then the namespace is of no concern to you; that's just the XML schema namespace. It should be as easy as `SELECT [key], [name], [age] FROM @T FOR XML PATH('person')`. Season with `ROOT` to taste.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This was actually pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments you can get simple element output as easy as the `FOR XML PATH ('person')`

To generate both schema and xlm that conforms start here:

```
create table person
  ([key] int,
   [name] varchar(50),
   [age] int);
go

insert into person values (1, 'Anakin', 23),(2, 'Jill', 40);
go

select * from person FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA;
```

If you require explicit element names or schema names you'll need to swap out the `XML AUTO` with `XML EXPLICIT` and provide your own schema document.

More info on `inline XSD` here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/generate-an-inline-xsd-schema?view=sql-server-2017

More info on `XML EXPLICIT` here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017